# Gulp - TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'cwd' of bower / bootstrap.css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, command-line, gulp, bower

I'm just getting to grips with Gulp.js and this is the only error I can't seem to get around.

I have install bootstrap via bower, and I'm trying to minify the bootstrap css.

Here's my gulp task;

```
gulp.task('minifycss', function() {
gulp.src('www/css/animate.css', 'www/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css')
    .pipe(minifycss({compatibility: 'ie8'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('www-deploy/css/'));
});
```

However when I run my main gulp task. It states that the file is "read only"

```
Karls-MacBook-Pro:cmp-2015 karltaylor$ gulp
[13:48:50] Using gulpfile ~/Documents/web/cmp-2015/gulpfile.js
[13:48:50] Starting 'sassMin'...
[13:48:50] Finished 'sassMin' after 12 ms
[13:48:50] Starting 'minifycss'...
[13:48:50] 'minifycss' errored after 508 μs
[13:48:50] TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'cwd' of www/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
    at Object.gs.createStream (/Users/karltaylor/Documents/web/cmp-2015/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/glob-stream/index.js:19:46)
    at Object.gs.create (/Users/karltaylor/Documents/web/cmp-2015/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/glob-stream/index.js:68:42)
    at Gulp.src (/Users/karltaylor/Documents/web/cmp-2015/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/lib/src/index.js:33:23)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/Users/karltaylor/Documents/web/cmp-2015/gulpfile.js:35:7)
    at module.exports (/Users/karltaylor/Documents/web/cmp-2015/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/Users/karltaylor/Documents/web/cmp-2015/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/Users/karltaylor/Documents/web/cmp-2015/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
    at /Users/karltaylor/Documents/web/cmp-2015/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:279:18
    at finish (/Users/karltaylor/Documents/web/cmp-2015/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:21:8)
    at module.exports (/Users/karltaylor/Documents/web/cmp-2015/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:60:3)
```

Things I've tried:

1. Reinstalling bootstrap
2. Moving the actual bootstrap.css file to my css file, however it does exactly the same thing.

EDIT: SOLVED = To use multiple sources you have to put them in an array.

Source: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/using-multiple-sources-in-one-task.md

Comment: I think this is happening because you have two files in your gulp.src. Try this line to verify (replace your gulp.src line) : `return gulp.src('www/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css')`

Comment: @topleft this did the trick! When using multiple source files looks like you have to put it inside an array or use merge-stream. - 

https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/using-multiple-sources-in-one-task.md

Comment: putting them inside array solved the problem. gulp.src([ , ])

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Like @topleft mentioned, it was error in the syntax from using multiple files in my gulp.src. To use multiple sources you need to put them in an array.

Example:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    return gulp.src(['foo/*', 'bar/*'])
        .pipe(concat('result.txt'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue when I tried to output 2 css files and I didn't use array [].

**Instead of:**

```
gulp.src('www/css/animate.css', 'www/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css')
    .pipe(minifycss({compatibility: 'ie8'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('www-deploy/css/'));
});
```

**Use this:**

```
gulp.src(['www/css/animate.css', 'www/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'])
    .pipe(minifycss({compatibility: 'ie8'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('www-deploy/css/'));
});
```

**Explanation:**

```
gulp.src(['./file1.scss', './file2.scss']);
```

Answer (score 2):

alternatively you could also try with

```
return gulp.src('www/**/*.css')
```

it should add every .css in your directories if thats the wanted effect

Comment: the order is important in this case! Then you can't do it.